# rails faraday for API call Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, faraday

I am getting a undefined method `body' error with a faraday call to an API;

URL - https://api.company.com/api/v1/dept/person/query/empid/22435678

I need to pass a username and password through as well. Here is what I am trying. What am I doing wrong?

```
  require 'faraday'
  require 'faraday/net_http'
  Faraday.default_adapter = :net_http


  def show

    @response = Faraday.new('https://api.company.com/api/v1/dept/person/query/empid/22435678') do |conn|
      conn.request :authorization, :basic, 'testuser', '77hfhncqjwnd'
    end

  end
```

Comment: What is the full error message and what line causes the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've only set up Faraday object and you're not sending an actual request with it.

```
# NOTE: configure faraday
api = Faraday.new('https://api.company.com/api/v1/dept/person/query/empid/22435678') do |conn|
  conn.request :authorization, :basic, 'testuser', '77hfhncqjwnd'
end

# NOTE: send requests to api `get`, `post` etc.
@response = api.get.body
```

This is the preferred set up:

```
api = Faraday.new('https://api.company.com/') do |conn|
  conn.request :authorization, :basic, 'testuser', '77hfhncqjwnd'
  # conn.response :json # automatically parse responses as json, if needed
end

@response = api.get("api/v1/dept/person/query/empid/22435678").body
```

*https://lostisland.github.io/faraday/usage/*

Comment: Ahhh awesome. Thanks! That did it. Any tips or articles on parsing the response and splitting the fields out?

Comment: is it `json`? use `conn.response :json` to auto parse it into a hash.